# Show that every non-zero proper ideal of $R$ can be written as a product of finitely many prime ideals of $R$, determined uniquely, upto order.

Tags: commutative-algebra, proof-explanation

> > **Theorem** $:$
> >
> > ---
> >
> > Let $R$ be a Noetherian domain such that it is integrally closed and every non-zero prime ideal of $R$ is maximal. Then every non-zero proper ideal of $R$ can be written as a product of finitely many prime ideals, determined uniquely, upto order.
> >
> > **Proof** $:$
> >
> > Let $S$ denote the collection of all non-zero proper ideals of $R$ which cannot be factored into product of finitely many prime ideals. if possible let $S \neq \varnothing.$ Let $A \in S$ be such that $A \supseteq p_1p_2 \cdots p_m$ 
> >     with $m$ minimal. Clearly $m \neq 1.$ $\exists$ a prime ideal $p$ such that $p_1p_2 \cdots p_m \subseteq p.$ $\implies$ some $p_i$ say $p_1 \subseteq p.$ But since every non-zero prime ideal of $R$ is maximal so we have $p_1 = p.$ But then $p_2p_3 \cdots p_m \subseteq Ap^{-1} \subseteq pp^{-1} = R.$ **Therefore $\text {Ap}^{-1} \notin \text S.$** So $Ap^{-1} = q_1 q_2 \cdots q_r \implies A = pq_1q_2 \cdots q_r,$ a contradiction. Hence $S = \varnothing.$

In the above proof I dont understand why $Ap^{-1} \notin S.$ Would anybody please help me in understanding this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Because $Ap^{-1}$ contains a product of fewer than $m$ prime ideals and $m$ was the minimal number among the ideals in $S$, so $Ap^{-1}$ is not an element of $S$.  Though actually there appears to be a slight issue with whether or not $Ap^{-1}$ is proper, given how the argument is phrased.

Comment: However this is easily fixed by noting that if $Ap^{-1}=R$, then $A=p$, so we can assume wlog that $Ap^{-1}$ is proper.

Comment: Yeah! Got it. Thanks @jgon for your kind help.